# how to find and replace multiple text files?

Tags: list, replace, find

Following is my code

```
oldname= open('oldportname.txt').read().split('\n')
newname =open('newportname.txt').read().split('\n')
find_replace = dict(zip(oldname, newname))

with open('data.txt') as data:
    with open('data_newname.txt', 'w') as new_data:
        for line in data:
            for key in find_replace:
                if key in line:
                    line = line.replace(key, find_replace[key])
            new_data.write(line)
```

I have three files,
data.txt
AD_WEB_TCP9389
AOL
Bittorrent
BOOTPC
UDP_67
BOOTPS
UDP_68
EPM_TCP135

Oldportname(find):
AD_WEB_TCP9389
AOL
Bittorrent
BOOTPC
UDP_67
BOOTPS
UDP_68
EPM_TCP135

newname(Replace):
AD-WEB_TCP_9389
AOL
BITTORRENT
BOOTPS_UDP_67
BOOTPS_UDP_67
BOOTPC_UDP_68
BOOTPC_UDP_68
EPMAP_TCP_135

I am getting weird output 
AD-WEB_TCP_9389(Correct)
AOL (Correct)
BITTORRENT (Correct)
BOOTPC_BOOTPC_UDP_68_BOOTPC_BOOTPC_UDP_68_UDP_67  (WRONG)
BOOTPC_BOOTPC_UDP_68_UDP_67 (WRONG)
BOOTPC_BOOTPC_UDP_68 (WRONG)
BOOTPC_UDP_68
EPMAP_EPMAP_TCP_135  (WRON)

Comment: You are missing the language tag